# Symfony Translations not working in prod

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I am trying to implement the symfony translations ... In dev works perfectly but not in prod.

**parameters.yml**

```
parameters:
    locale: pt_BR
```

**config.yml**

```
framework:
    translator: { fallback: "%locale%" }
```

and messages.pt_BR.yml in \Resources\translations\

```
"Bad credentials" :         "E-mail/senha inválidos"
"User account is disabled.": "Usuário inativo"
```

**.twig** i use:
    {{ error.message|trans }}

Again, in DEV works perfectly, but not in PROD.

I have to do some more configuration?

Comment: "Not working" is rarely a useful error report. Are you getting any kind of error output or error logs that can help? Furthermore, when you say "DEV" and "PROD" are you referring to symfony's environments, or different server environments?

Comment: sorry Peter, i refer to the symfony's environments.

Comment: have you cleared the prod cache?

Comment: Thanks Marino!!! Missed execute the command: **php app/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug**

Comment: Definitely get used to clearing the production cache. That's the "is it plugged in?" of Symfony development.

Comment: Add it as an answer and accept it so the question is answered, thx.

Answer (score 2):

The cache has to be cleared - as [Marino mentioned it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26183801/symfony-translations-not-working-in-prod#comment41056031_26183801).

```
php app/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug
```

Comment: For Symfony 3.0+ - **php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod**